# Is there an equation that will graph the shape or predict the maximum amplitude of a single sample impulse fed through a One-Pole LPF?

Tags: lowpass-filter, infinite-impulse-response, impulse-response, amplitude, envelope

If you feed a single sample impulse of a given amplitude through a One-Pole LPF you get an envelope that looks like this:

[image]

The output of the LPF from its peak will settle into an exponential decay where time to reach $1/e$ amplitude is given by $1/(2πf)$ where $f$ is the cutoff frequency of the LPF.

I am wondering if there's any way to predict the maximum amplitude of the envelope from the sample rate, LPF cutoff freq, and amplitude of the single sample impulse. In general, is there a non-recursive equation that can describe or approximate the curve that results from these three factors?

If such an equation can be developed or exists, then one can take the derivative and solve where it equals zero to find the max.

Is this possible?

Alternatively, I can solve it numerically by just iterating through a temporary setup of a single sample impulse into an LPF of the given parameters until `(output_1 < output)`. This will find the max as well but this is tedious and computationally consuming.

I would hope some equation can do this faster.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: you should know that the impulse response that you have graphed there is not from a One-pole filter.  It is at least two poles..

Comment: and *"single sample Dirac impulse"* is a misnomer.  you might mean "single-sample Kronecker impulse"

Comment: Okay thanks. I took out the "Dirac" if that was a misnomer. But I'm not sure what you mean about the filter type. Are you saying the shape is wrong for a One-Pole and that's how you know it's not? Either way, I think the principle is the same. I am referring to a filter like https://www.earlevel.com/main/2012/12/15/a-one-pole-filter/ where as the author there says: "Note that if you feed the one-pole lowpass an impulse, it will yield a perfect exponential decay. To look at it another way, the feedback path is an iterative solution to calculating an exponential curve."

Comment: all this depends, mike, if your problem is about continuous-time (like an RC LPF) or is a discrete time.  either way, if it's one-pole, the maximum occurs immediately and it's about scaling.  if it's two-pole, you can have the peak occur at some later time.  but how big the peak is about scaling.

Comment: *//Are you saying the shape is wrong for a One-Pole and that's how you know it's not?//*

Yes.

Comment: Oh I see. Yes thanks robert. I debugged out some data from the One-Pole and yes it just gives you the maximum right away. Thank you for clarifying that. So to get that type of smooth envelope response pictured you need a 2nd order LPF or higher. I guess there will be no way to calculate the max output then except to iterate through it. Do you have any thoughts on how filter structure would change the response decay rate? I had been told previously 2nd order LPF's don't have so simply predictable decay rates. And I'm not sure how resonance settings would affect the peak or decay rate. Thoughts?

Comment: *//  I guess there will be no way to calculate the max output then except to iterate through it. //*  I think that is correct.  I know it can be done with very few iterations using the Newton-Raphson method. essentially, if the LPF is over damped (which means a Q of less than 1/2), then the impulse response is the difference of two exponential functions.  but there is no closed-form solution.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: There is actually a closed-form solution for the location of the maximum of the impulse response, if that is what you meant.

Comment: gee, @MattL. , do you mean the 2nd-order LPF impulse response? i don't think it makes a difference whether continuous-time or discrete-time. i was working on this very problem (but regarding the envelope of the output of a form of comb filters with feedback) less than two years ago.  So you're saying that taking the derivative of:

$$ h(t) = A \big(e^{-\alpha t} - e^{-\beta t} \big) \qquad 0 < \alpha < \beta $$

and setting that derivative to zero has a closed form solution?  I wonder what I am thinking wrong?

Comment: Maybe it does.  The problem was for me was given an $\alpha$ (which is the dominant pole), what value of $\beta$ will put the maximum where I want it.  **That** must be solved with Newton-Raphson or some iterative method.

Comment: you're right.  the maximum occurs at:

$$ t_\mathrm{max} = \frac{\log(\beta) - \log(\alpha)}{\beta - \alpha}  $$

but given an $\alpha$, solving for a $\beta$ that will put $t_\mathrm{max}$ where you might want it, that requires an iterative algorithm.  i used Newton-Raphson.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Yes, your $t_{max}$ is the same as the one in my answer below. You're right that the other problem, namely solving for $\beta$ given $\alpha$ and $t_{max}$, doesn't have a closed form solution, unless one would call an expression using the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) "closed form".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, an impulse response with the shape shown in your question can only be obtained by a system with two real-valued poles. In continuous time, with two distinct poles, the total impulse response is

$$h(t)=\frac{e^{-\alpha_1t}-e^{-\alpha_2t}}{\alpha_2-\alpha_1}u(t)\tag{1}$$

It's a basic exercise to determine the location of the maximum of $(1)$, and the result is

$$t_{max}=\frac{\log\left(\frac{\alpha_1}{\alpha_2}\right)}{\alpha_1-\alpha_2},\qquad\alpha_1\neq\alpha_2\tag{2}$$

For $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\alpha$, the total impulse response is

$$h(t)=te^{-\alpha t}u(t)\tag{3}$$

and the location of the maximum is

$$t_{max}=\frac{1}{\alpha}\tag{4}$$

The figure below shows an example of an impulse response $(1)$ with $\alpha_1=0.4$ and $\alpha_2=0.6$, and with the location of the maximum predicted by $(2)$.

[image]